# Calling javascript apps with slash commands

Tags: javascript, slack-api

I'm building a small bot for my Slack team, and at the moment I want to send a request to my server whenever a certain slash-command is issued (and then depending on the channel, the server will or will not respond).

Now, I know this can come across as a stupid question, but I can't figure out how to do it. I've been trying different bits of code to start worknig on this, but when using the command, Slack displays my code instead of an answer.

In the configuration menu, I set the request URL as `http://IP/path-to-directory/abc.js`. Is it right or wrong? And if it's right, any pointers about where the problem could come from?

Thanks you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think calling a .js script directly will work. It has to be something that the web server can execute, e.g. a PHP script or you need to run it on a node.js server.

Comment: So basically an empty HTML page, with only the script in it?

Comment: Hmm. on second thought, the slack server will most likely not execute JS on HTML page...

Comment: Ah, crap. Do you have any idea of a method which would work in this case?